# Get dates between a certain duration in yii2 model

Tags: php, yii2

i have a truck and truck history table they have the following structure

```
table trucks
  id,created_at, ....
```

table truck_history

```
id, truck_id, status, created_at
```

THe truck_history saves severaltruck histories eg:expired, created, deleted

So what am trying to do is to get all trucks created on a certain date and even those which could have expired on a certain date

am using tbl_trucks to determine the date that they were created and truck history to determine the expiry date

so i have tried

```
$query = V4TblTrucks::find()  //tbl_trucks
          ->leftJoin('tbl_truck_history', 'tbl_truck_history.truck_id = tbl_trucks.id')
        ->andWhere(["between", "tbl_trucks.created_at", $ts1, $ts2])
```

when a key is supplied in the frontend i would like to check even the expired trucks on that duration so ive added

```
      if (array_key_exists('non_reg', $arr)) {
        if ($arr['non_reg']) {
            $query->orFilterWhere([
                'or',
                ['IN', 'tbl_truck_history.status', [28, 25, 24]]
            ])->orWhere(["between", "tbl_truck_history.created_at", $ts1, $ts2]);
        }
    }
```

So the second part is the one which fails to work. with both filter where and orWhere conditions

What am i missiong out.
Nb: $ts1 and $ts2 are times passed from the frontend

Comment: replace orFilterWhere with andFilterWhere

Comment: are you using the `SearchModel` to filter the results or just using active record query in the controller? and you are saying **when a key is supplied in the frontend i would like to check even the expired trucks on that duration** i cant see how you are filtering the exxpired trucks in the first query? you are not checking the `status` anywhere, if you have a raw mysql query prepaired please add it too

Comment: I don't think you need the Filter version if there will always be a search value, but in any case try simply `orWhere(['tbl_truck_history.status' => [28, 25, 24]])` for that part. Use `$query->createCommand()->getRawSql()` to see what it's generating overall.